# How to save the ownership with Secure Copy in UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, jboss, redhat

I was wondering if there is a way to recursively secure copy and preserve the ownership. I have tried the following:

```
    sudo scp -rp [local server directory] username@remoteserver[remote server directory]
    rsync -av /local/dir server:/remote/dir
```

Both of them couldn't preserve the ownership. The file owner was jboss, but when I secure copy, the user automatically becomes the owner on remote server.

Comment: Checked this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43605/how-do-i-copy-a-folder-keeping-owners-and-permissions-intact  ??

Comment: I have checked that before. This is a secure copy not regular copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be possible.  First, consider that the local user "jboss" may not exist on the remote server.  Or, if user "jboss" *does* exist on the remote server, there is no guarantee that the UID of local user "jboss" is the same as the UID of the remote user "jboss" (remember that Unix ownership is always in terms of IDs, not names; tools like `ls` look up the textual names to display for an ID based on the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files, but to the filesystem/kernel, it's the IDs, not the names, which are relevant).

Next, consider that preserving the local ownership on a remote server is effectively "giving a file away" on that remote server, which Unix usually does not allow; see [this Unix StackExchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27374) for a good discussion about why that is.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This answer is much better than the past where everyone said it's possible but not really explained how.